# customized installation of pyodbc

Tags: python, unix, pyodbc

I've encountered a tricky problem here. The situation is:

I want to compile pyodbc by using

```
    python setup.py install
```

under Linux 12. However, I get the following error

```
    fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I guess it looks for unixODBC so I try to install it. But the problem is, I do not have privilege to the root directory, so I have installed it in my home directory.

My question then, is how can I redirect the pyodbc to look for my customized unixODBC path?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source from https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc and run

```
python setup.py build_ext install -L/your/libpython/path/
```

or create a setup.cfg file containing

```
[build_ext]
library_dirs="/your/libpython/path/"
```

then run

```
python setup build_ext install
```